# Access violation when freeing char* in tesseract, c++

Tags: c++, tesseract, access-violation

Using tesseract ocr,
this is my part of code:

```
        Pix *pix = pixRead("mylocation/my.jpg");

        api.SetImage(pix);
        char* result = new char[100];
        result = api.GetUTF8Text();
        new1 = atof(result);

        cout << "result: " << new1 << endl;

        delete[] result;
```

I get access violation when i delete result.

I saw another post suggesting that to "rebuilt tesseract in VS2015", when i am using VS2015. How to do that?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have a memory leak also. When you assign a new value to `result`, the allocated pointer is lost. You don't need to allocate memory before calling `GetUTF8Text()`

Comment: Short version: `new1 = atof(api.GetUTF8Text());`.

Comment: Finally I use another c++ wrapper library and there is no memory leak. My thought is that the memory leak was caused by the original library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I use another c++ wrapper library and there is no memory leak. My thought is that the memory leak was caused by the original library. Thanks for every one's help.

Comment: Good to hear you fixed it :)

Answer (score 5):

Simply put, you do not have ownership of result to delete the object. I'll explain why.

on line 4, `char* result = new char[100];` This will allocate 100 bytes of memory, and store the location in the result pointer. Assume this memory address happens to be 0xF00.

on line 5, `result = api.GetUTF8Text();` This method (appears to) return a pointer, This means the memory-address in 'result' is being over-written by the new pointer. Perhaps the location of the internal-buffer provided by the api is 0xBA2. As you haven't stored it anywhere else, the 0xF00 address is now lost!

On line ten, `delete[] result;` - This tells the system to delete the memory pointed-to by result, in this case, my hypothetical 0xBA2, memory **owned by the api, not the memory you allocated** - The system detected this, and threw an appropriate error.

**If The API returns a pointer**

In this case, you can replace lines 4 and 5 with `char * result = api.GetUTF8Text()`. And remove the delete statement entirely.

**some helpful advice:**

Note that modern c++ (and most compilers support) [shared_ptr, unique_ptr, and others](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) - It's generally much better to use these, rather than free/delete.

> If you leave resource management to handles and containers relying on RAII, rather than littering your code with pointer, news and deletes, you don’t encounter resource leaks or write to freed memory. ~ [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2080042)

Comment: I have tried to assign char* result = api.GetUTF8Text() and remove "delete". There isn't any error but memory keep increasing still. I think every time api.GetUTF8Text() is called, the previous memory is not freed.

Comment: Did you also remove the `new char[100]`, If you didn't that might explain it, you won't need that anymore.

Also, consider what API you are using! Does the API have a special call to free memory it allocated? Or could the API have a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it shouldn't be:

```
*result = api.GetUTF8Text();
```

Without the star you are resetting the pointer to another location (leaving the one made with *new* operator). When you try to free it later you get your error.

That's one option. Otherwise if there should be *result* without the star, you shouldn't allocate the memory with *new* before.

Comment: I imagine it's quite unlikely (perhaps not possible) that the method would write to a lvalue in that fashion.

I expect the user doesn't need to allocate a buffer for that method.

Answer (score 0):

the memory leak is, that you do not free what you malloc'ed()

"result = " moves the pointer to some other place, in this case to what the api gives you

perhaps "strcpy (result, api.GetUTF8Text() )" is what you wanted?